# How to iterate a synchronized treeMap?

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

Currently have this implementation:

```
static Map s_AvailableGameTables = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<Integer,Table>());
```

How can I iterate over all it's content from the start to the end like an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the entries (key-value pairs in the map):

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Table> entry : s_AvailableGameTables.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key = " + entry.getKey() + ", value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Did the same before I was asking giving compile error: incompatible types

Comment: Ofcourse you must not use the raw type `Map` to declare your variable `s_AvailableGameTables`, instead you must declare it with type parameters: `static Map<Integer, Table> s_AvailableGameTables` as Jim says in his answer. See [tutorial about generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the declaration is

```
static Map<Integer,Table> s_AvailableGameTables = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<Integer,Table>());
```

(not just `Map`)

The following will iterate over all key/value pairs:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Table> e : s_AvailableGameTables.entrySet())
{
    int key = e.getKey();
    Table tbl = e.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but,  
what is the difference between my declaration to yours ,I mean what does it change across my program?

Comment: by the way only working with this declaration in that way: for(Map.Entry<Integer,Table> currentTable: ServerMain.s_AvailableGameTables.entrySet())

Comment: If `s_AvailableGameTables` is just an unparameterized `Map`, then you cannot write the code as-is for iteration.  The compiler would assume `Map<?,?>` as the type and then the `entrySet()` method return value would be incompatible with the declaration in the `for` statement. You could get around that with casts, but that's what generics are supposed to eliminate.